# Does Cognito Forms support data collection and printing of long forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

I am trying to create a medical questionnaire for new clients to fill out at a healthcare practice. The information is quite long and detailed and once the form is filled out at the patients home it needs to be sent back to the practice via email and it then needs to be able to be printed on 2-3 normal portrait A4 pages. Does Cognito Forms support this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) can be used for small, two question forms, to long 50-page forms with hundreds of fields.  You can print entries via administration, which print in a read-only format in the same layout as the form.  You can also use this capability to Save as PDF (in Chrome) or print to PDF in other browsers.

You can configure Cognito Forms to send email notifications and confirmations when a form is submitted.  The notifications would go back to the practice in this case, alerting them of a new entry, and confirmations can be sent to the patient, letting them know their information has been safely delivered.

However, at least in the US, email notifications and confirmations should NOT be configured to include patient information, as email transmission is not secure.  Instead, the confirmation (if configured) should politely thank the patient for their submission (without details) and the notification should simply alert the practice of the new entry, with a link to review the information in Cognito Forms.  In the US, sending patient information via email is a major HIPAA violation, and I suspect that similar laws apply in most other countries.